# Transform coeftest in r to a nice looking table

Tags: r

I have had some trouble with producing a table that presents the result from the "coeftest" that simultaneously looks visually appealing. I have tried stargazer and it does not work, it only prints a lot of text and does not format the table.

So does anyone know how to nicely format fixed effects regressions and also print the results from the coeftest in a nice table so it looks visually appealing?

Preferably I would like to print multiple tables next to each other.
This is the code I'm currently using for my fixed effects model:

`plm(ret ~ Dummy 1* Dummy 2+`
`Dummy 1 +`
`Dummy 2 + ROA + Leverage,`
`data = df,`
`index = c("entity"),`
`model = "within")`

`coeftest(model1, vcov. = vcovHC, type = "HC1")`

I have tried stargazer, both with htlm, pdf and latex output, did not work. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Use texreg, modelsummary or huxtable::huxreg. Avoid stargazer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer how to make stargazer work somewhat. It is rather a Latex page that you can enter the weird code in so it transforms it to a table.

here is a helpful YT video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQ2Dd3CSa0U
Here is the website: https://www.overleaf.com/project/635e88d411c2db7117312e69

Hopefully I'm able to help someone. I have spend hours trying to figure it out :)

Comment: Dear Hanna, I'm glad you figured this out. While helpful, links may become inoperable in the future. It would be useful to others if your answer provided a reproducible example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).